# Unable to install gems simple_xlsx_writer and fast_xs

Tags: ruby

I am trying to install gems simple_xlsx_writer and fast_xs. But I am getting the same below  error for both gems. Even for simple_xlsx_writer.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing simple_xlsx_writer:
                ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        "C:/Program Files/Ruby187/bin/ruby.exe" extconf.rb
checking for assert.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
                --with-opt-dir
                --without-opt-dir
                --with-opt-include
                --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
                --with-opt-lib
                --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
                --with-make-prog
                --without-make-prog
                --srcdir=.
                --curdir
                --ruby=C:/Program Files/Ruby187/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in D:/Users/pavana.prasad/.gem/New Folder/gems/fast_xs-0.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/Users/pavana.prasad/.gem/New Folder/gems/fast_xs-0.8.0/ext/fast_xs/gem_make.ou
```

Please help me to install the gem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you used RubyInstaller, you will also need DevKit to build gems with C extensions. The simple_xlsx gem depends on fast_xs, which uses C extensions.

http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/